# implement 30 days time interval in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I am re-posting this question as I have still not found an optimal solution.

I am designing a table that captures patients' blood samples information. It has a patient ID and a collection Date - date on which patients' blood samples were collected.

The table has three additional columns - episode_number, episode_start_date and episode_end_date. An episode is nothing but a 30 day time window. Any samples collected within 30 days belong to the same episode. For example, a patient submitted his first blood sample on Jan-01-2013, and the next blood sample on Jan -19-2013. Since both the collection dates fall within the same "30days window" they belong to the same episode_number (episode 1). The start date of this episode would be the first ever collection date (Jan-01-2013), and end date would be start date + 30 days (Jan 30-01-2013). Any number of patient blood samples collected within this date range belong to episode_number = 1.

Let's say the same patient submits another blood sample on Feb-04-2013. Since this collection date is outside of 30 days window of episode_number = 1, it would belong to a new episode_number (episode 2). The start date of this episode would be Feb-04-2013, and end date would be + 30 days i.e. March 02-2013.

Let's say the table that looks like the example below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Patient ID | Collection_Date | Episode_Number     |Episode_Start_Date | Episode_End_Date |
1          | 2013-01-01      |                    |                   |                  |
1          | 2013-01-01      |                    |                   |                  |   
1          | 2013-01-05      |                    |                   |                  |
1          | 2013-02-04      |                    |                   |                  |  
1          | 2013-02-06      |                    |                   |                  |   
1          | 2013-05-01      |                    |                   |                  |
1          | 2013-08-01      |                    |                   |                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need a query that would populate episode_number, episode_start_Date, and episode_end_date based on the logic described in my text above. The result of the query should populate the table values mentioned below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Patient ID | Collection_Date |Episode_number     |Episode_Start_Date| Episode_End_Date |
1          | 2013-01-01      |1                  |2013-01-01        | 2013-01-30       |
1          | 2013-01-01      |1                  |2013-01-01        | 2013-01-30       |
1          | 2013-01-05      |1                  |2013-01-05        | 2013-01-30       |
1          | 2013-02-04      |2                  |2013-02-04        | 2013-03-02       |
1          | 2013-02-06      |2                  |2013-02-04        | 2013-02-04       |
1          | 2013-05-01      |3                  |2013-05-01        | 2013-05-30       |
1          | 2013-08-01      |4                  |2013-08-01        | 2013-08-30       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Things to remember:

1. An episode = 30 days time window
2. First episode start date = first ever collection date
3. First epsiode end date = first episode start date + 30 days
4. All samples collected within the same 30 days window belong to same episode.
5. if the collection date of any sample is greater than the episode end date of the previous collection, then it belongs to a new episode where the episode start date = collection date; and episode end date =  start date + 30 days.

I hope my question is clear to understand. My table has over 3 million records, so I not only need a solution that works, but a solution that has optimal performance. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Ashish

Comment: What's wrong with `DATEADD`?

Comment: Simply using DATEADD wouldn't solve the problem. We have to first check whether or not collection date is within the last '30 days time interval'. If it is within the last interval, it gets same start date and end date. Otherwise we create a new start date and end date for it.

Comment: *"The start date of this episode would be Feb-04-2013, and end date would be + 30 days i.e. March 02-2013."* Do you mind pulling out your calendar and, perhaps, explaining this arithmetic? March 2 is 30 days from Jan 31, which might be a fencepost error (if you're supposed to start on Feb 1), but still needs some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option to change your table design, I recommend Mike Sherill's answer.

If you don't have the option, the following should work, but the performance may be poor:

```
with cte as
(select [Patient ID],
        min(Collection_Date) Collection_Date,
        1 Episode_Number,
        min(Collection_Date) Episode_Start_Date,
        Dateadd(d,29,min(Collection_Date)) Episode_End_Date
 from sampleTable
 group by [Patient ID]
 union all
 select s.[Patient ID],
        s.Collection_Date Collection_Date,
        c.Episode_Number+1 Episode_Number,
        s.Collection_Date Episode_Start_Date,
        Dateadd(d,29,s.Collection_Date) Episode_End_Date
 from cte c
 join sampleTable s 
   on c.[Patient ID] = s.[Patient ID] and 
      c.Episode_End_Date < s.Collection_Date and
      not exists (select null
                  from sampleTable i
                  where c.[Patient ID] = i.[Patient ID] and
                        c.Episode_End_Date < i.Collection_Date and
                        i.Collection_Date < s.Collection_Date)
 )
select cte.[Patient ID],
       st.Collection_Date,
       cte.Episode_Number,
       cte.Episode_Start_Date,
       cte.Episode_End_Date
from cte
join sampleTable st 
  on st.[Patient ID] = cte.[Patient ID] and 
     st.Collection_Date between cte.Episode_Start_Date and cte.Episode_End_Date 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e37f/4).

Comment: Thank-you, this is definitely one way of solving my problem. I will give it a try, although I am afraid about query performance when using CTE recursion with over few million records.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm going to leave this up for a while, but this doesn't implement the unexpressed constraint that collection_date must be between episode_start_date and episode_end_date.)

Let's look at part of this table for a minute.

```
Patient ID | Collection_Date |Episode_number     |Episode_Start_Date| Episode_End_Date |
1          | 2013-01-01      |1                  |2013-01-01        | 2013-01-30       |
1          | 2013-01-01      |1                  |2013-01-01        | 2013-01-30       |
```

Duplicate rows. This table has no key.

What *different things* are these two *identical* rows supposed to be telling us?

This kind of table cries out for real keys--not just another ID number.

A table for storing information about patient episodes would probably need to look something like this.

```
create table patient_episodes (
  patient_id integer not null,
  episode_number integer not null
    check (episode_number > 0),
  primary key (patient_id, episode_number),
  foreign key (patient_id, episode_number) 
    references samples (patient_id, episode_number),

  episode_start_date date not null,
  episode_end_date date not null,
  check (episode_end_date = episode_start_date + interval '30 days')
);
```

You'd *need* to declare a foreign key reference from patient_episodes to samples initially, because patient_episodes is empty. It's not clear to me whether it should stay that way after both tables are populated and stable. (Probably not, but I'd hate to guess.)

Your table of samples is still structurally troubled, because it doesn't have a key. How you resolve that problem will have some influence on the structure of the patient_episodes table.

Comment: Sherrill: Thanks for your comment. You are right in my example above I should have specified a primary key. My original table is much more structured than my example above. Unfortunately I am unable to publish metadata of my original table due to confidentiality reasons. But Let's assume my table above has sample_id, which can be used as primary key.

Comment: @AshishSachdeva: An artificial key--another ID number--won't solve the problem of duplicate data.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention this table is demoralized because it is supposed to be a Fact table for data warehouse, not transactional processing. Fact tables are demoralized on purpose to optimize select statements.